# NodeJS, Multi-FileWatcher, Socket.IO and interaction with the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) and I wonder how to **properly** send the content of several files using [FS](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html) and [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/).

My problem is more about *best practices* on Node/javascript than the actual 'raw' logic of my scripts.

So, the purpose of my app is to watch a log File (File1.log) and a Result File (File2.log).
Until the File2.log contains a string (such as "Done", or "Error"), I need to continue sending the result of the File1.log to the client.

When the key ("Error","Done") has been read, I send  the result to the client and have to launch the same process for another couple of log/result files - after having closed the FileWatcher on the first one.

In the end, I need to close the connection and stop all of the sleeping FileWatcher processes.

The 'streaming' of my files is working pretty well, but I am confused about the best way to switch between the differents FileWatch Processes and how to notify the client.

**Server.JS**

```
/*
* [SomeCode]...
*/
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {

    //Starting the process for the first couple of files    
    client.on('logA', function (res) {

        var PATH_to_A = "path/to/A/directory/";
        readFile(client,PATH_to_A);

    });

    //Starting the process for the seconde couple of files
    client.on('logB', function (res) {
        //I need to stop the first readFile Watcher process


        var PATH_to_B = "path/to/B/directory/";
        readFile(client,PATH_to_B); 
    });     
});


function readFile(client,PATH){

    var File1 = path.join(PATH,'File1.log');
    var File2 = path.join(PATH,'File2.log');

    //Get the file stats
    fs.stat(File1,function(err,stats){
        if (err) throw err;
        //Send the data;
    });


    //Watch the first file
    var w1 = fs.watch(File1,function(status, file){

        if(status == "change"){
            fs.stat(File1,function(err,stats){
                if (err) throw err;
                //Send the data;
            });
        }

    });
    //Watch the second file
    var w2 = fs.watch(File2,function(status, file){
        if(status == "change"){
            fs.readFile(File2, "utf8", function (err, body) {
                if (err) throw err;
                //Some Code....
                client.emit('done',body);   
            });
        }
    });
    //Closing FileWatcher
    client.on('ack',function(){
        w1.close();
        w2.close();
    });
}
```

**Client.JS**

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000');

   //On connect, waiting for the first couple of files          
    socket.on('connect', function(server) {
        socket.emit('init',data);
        socket.emit('logA');

    });
    //If the first process is done, i ask for the second couple of files
    socket.on('done',function(message){
        socket.emit('ack');
        socket.emit('logB');    
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I finally succeeded using the https://github.com/caolan/async module.